# How to populate new field according to string content of another field using VB script?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, vbscript

I want to populate a new field called *Letting* according to the string value found in another field. If 'ASP' or 'Q' is in field *ExternalRE* then I want 1 in *Letting*, everything else to be 0.

Here is my erroneous script:

```
dim x
if 'ASP' in [ExternalRe] then 
  x = 1 
if 'Q' in [ExternalRe] then 
  x = 1 
else x = 0 
end if
```

Letting = x

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps something like

```
dim x
if InStr([ExternalRe],"ASP")>0 then
    x = 1
end if
if InStr([ExternalRe],"Q")>0 then
    x = 1
else
    x = 0
end if

Letting = x
```

vbscript seems to be picky about quotes around strings too - single quotes can give an error.

EDIT:
depending on how you actually want to calculate the Letting field, you may want your logic like:

```
dim x
if InStr([ExternalRe],"ASP")>0 or InStr([ExternalRe],"Q")>0 then
    x = 1
else
    x = 0
end if
```

otherwise, if "Q" is not in ExternalRe, x will always be zero.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I ran your code and it comes up with error: expected 'If'. Any ideas what that might mean?

Comment: oops - think i failed to end the first if statement. i've edited the code - i'll test it to check... however, as written, if Q is not in your Letting column. x will be zero no matter if ASP is in the string